# beginner python: my isfile() check stopped working

Tags: python, if-statement

1. This section was working and now it's NOT working. There's a possibility the working version didn't save, but this seems like a specific failure in code. I can't see where the problem might be. The `print #debug` works outside of the `if isfile` check but not inside. The Console output below isn't the whole directory, but the working loop does output the full list of files.
2. Also, is it possible to put a print("string" + list) on the same line?
3. And once I get the isfile() working I need to check the file contains an `<HTML>` tag. Will I need to open/read file, then check text? Or is there some other way to scan a file?

Thank you!

```
def getChapterFiles(book):
    filepaths = getFilepaths(book)
    #print(filepaths) # debug #
    files = []
    chapters = []
    for book, filepaths, files in os.walk(book):
        for file in files:
            #print(os.path.join(book, file)) # debug #
            if os.path.isfile(file):
            ##and file.endswith(".html")
                chapters.append(os.path.join(book, file))           
                print(os.path.join(book, file)) # debug # 
    print("Chapters: ")
    print(chapters)        
    return chapters
```

CONSOLE outside `isfile` check:

```
D:\story_processing\test dirs\RR\Journey Into Darkness\Journey into Darkness -Chapter 6.html
Inside for loop, outside isfile: 
D:\story_processing\test dirs\RR\Journey Into Darkness\Journey Into Darkness -Chapter 7.html
Inside for loop, outside isfile: 
D:\story_processing\test dirs\RR\Journey Into Darkness\Journey into Darkness -Chapter 8.html
Chapters: 
[]
```

CONSOLE inside `isfile` check:

```
D:\story_processing\test dirs\RR\Journey Into Darkness\Journey Into Darkness -Chapter 4.html
Inside for loop, outside isfile: 
D:\story_processing\test dirs\RR\Journey Into Darkness\Journey into Darkness -Chapter 5.html
Inside for loop, outside isfile: 
D:\story_processing\test dirs\RR\Journey Into Darkness\Journey into Darkness -Chapter 6.html
Inside for loop, outside isfile: 
D:\story_processing\test dirs\RR\Journey Into Darkness\Journey Into Darkness -Chapter 7.html
Inside for loop, outside isfile: 
D:\story_processing\test dirs\RR\Journey Into Darkness\Journey into Darkness -Chapter 8.html
Chapters: 
[]
```

[Image of corresponding directory:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvvi0.png)

Comment: One question per question, please. StackOverflow is Q&A, not 3Q&3A.

Comment: Why do you do the isfile check? I think OS.walk makes sure that it is a file.

Comment: I want to make sure that it only pulls the files, not any sub dirs. Is there a better check?

Comment: Does the file have to contain the literal text _<HTML>_, or is something like _<html xmlns="​htt​p​:​/​/​w​ww.w3.org/1999/xhtml xml:lang="en">_ possible too?

Comment: @Mr Lister: I'll make a new question if I can't figure it out soon. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Please change name "book" with another variable name example "bk" :

```
for bk, filepaths, files in os.walk(book):
        for file in files:
            #print(os.path.join(bk, file)) # debug #
            if os.path.isfile(file):
            ##and file.endswith(".html")
                chapters.append(os.path.join(bk, file))           
                print(os.path.join(bk, file)) # debug #
```

2)

`print("string %s" % ["yours list"])`

Comment: Thanks for the print statement. My syntax was off: (mylist) instead of [mylist].

Comment: A follow-up Q: what's the reason of "bk" over "book"?

Comment: Becouse book one place was a method argument, in other place are variable in loop.

Answer (score 0):

1) i'd assume that the files are **not** in your working directory, which means that you have to test for the filepath rather than the filename:

```
if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(book, file)):
    # do something
```

---

2) just call `str(chapters)` explicitly (`print()` implies it, but string concatenation doesn't):

```
print("Chapters: " + str(chapters))
```

3) since you're working with html, i'd recommend looking towards [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), but it's hard to give recommendations without knowing what you're checking for. as @Aran-Fey said, one question at a time.

Comment: Thanks for item (2) :)  For (1), I have `os.chdir(os.path.normpath(working_dir))` but working_dir is where I'm writing files to. test_dir would be where I'm reading from. When the print is outside the isfile(), it reads the right directory. Do I need to chdir to the `read_from` dir for the `isfile()` ?

Comment: yes. it's like navigating in the explorer - if i send you to directory B and ask you if you see a file that is actually in directory A, you'll of course reply "no" (cause it's not there). however, i personally recommend working with absolute paths, as all that directory switching usually gives me headaches.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of years of learning Python, I prefer using `pathlib` as much as possible. `pathlib` has built in fuctions for `is_file()` and `stat().size` for file size. See [Python pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for full info.

```
import pathlib

p = pathlib.Path(r"c:\full\path_to\directory_root")
subdirs = [x for x in p.iterdir() if x.is_dir()] # returns all subdirectories of root p

# html files in subdirs separated out by subdirectory
all_subdirectory_files = []
for subdir in subdirs: 
    file_list = list(subdir.glob('**/*.html'))
    all_subdirectory_files.append(file_list)
for sd in all_subdirectory_files:
    print(f"{sd}")
```